# Python - Using the random module to give you a value in the range of [0.0, 1.0), multiply it, then round it

Tags: python, floating-point, range, rounding

```
import random
result = []
for i in range(0.0, 1.0):
    [random.randrange(5000) for i in range(5)]
```

Trying to figure out how to, using the random module, obtain five values in the range from [0.0, 1.0), multiplying each value spit out by 5000, and rounding it to zero decimal places all the while using the random() and range() functions.

Being new to Python, I've experimented with this question for some time now and am completely lost on how to go about this (especially given I need the range of floats). How would I go about resolving the float issue along with my multiplication/rounding/random and range function question?

Comment: All you want is random numbers from [0 to 5000) ?

Comment: No--but my code may be incorrectly written to do that--I am trying to get five values from [0.0 to 1.0) and then multiply each value by 5000 and round them to the closest zero decimal place

Comment: Here are some advices to put you on the good path :  
Do you want the inside of the loop to be called X times ? If so, use `for i in range(X)` and i will take the values 0..1..2 up to X-1.  
Here's the documentation for the random module : https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html . I'd advise you to look at the `random.random()` function, as it seems to have the value you want returned from random.

Comment: @HolyDanna As simple as it may seem, connecting your comment with another's suggested code now has me realizing just what the random.random() function--and the code as a whole--is doing. Thanks.

Comment: "I am trying to get five values from [0.0 to 1.0) and then multiply each value by 5000": You are essentially drawing random numbers from (the uniform distribution) [0,5000] when you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to draw five random numbers (from uniform distribution), multiply them by 5000, and then rounding them

```
[round(5000*random.random()) for i in range(5)]
```

You can also pull from a uniform distribution from 0 to 5000 to get the same result:

```
[round(random.uniform(0, 5000)) for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: If I am trying to have those initial values that will be producted five times then be multiplied by 5000 range from 0.0 to 1.0 how would I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "producted five times then be multiplied by 5000 range from 0.0 to 1.0"?

Comment: Actually, it just hit me what exactly your code is doing! Ignore my previous question.